# Python can't run to text file from visual studio code or atom, but writes with sublime text

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, atom-editor

Just very simple code. When I run the script from sublime text, it writes in the text file but when trying to run the script from Visual Studio Code or Atom (even when ran as admin) it won't write in the text file. While it's cool that it works with sublime text, sublime text can't run multiple scripts at the same time (and many other features). I can't figure out the problem or how to fix it, thanks.

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write('hello')
```

Comment: Unless you tell it differently, Sublime will execute `python` scripts with the current working directory set to be the same as the location the script is stored in, so `file.txt` will appear next to your script. Do VSC and Atom do the same thing? Perhaps the file is being written somewhere that you don't expect.

Comment: Yes visual studio maintains a directory in the users documents folder called "Visual Studio <year>", in that directory is a folder called "Projects", and in that directory you should see names that look familiar to you (since you created them).

Comment: Atom doesn't run any code out of the box, so it would be helpful to know which package you're using.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You said when you run a script in sublime text, it writes output to the text file. Which text file are you referring to? It reads like you are saying it writes to the same file that is read from?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using a plugin like [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)? After installing, click on the play button at the top-right side and code shall automatically run in your terminal.

Comment: With Code Runner you can also use keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+N